# How to get street view in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I am developing an application in which i am using maps. I will get the coordinates from the address which the user enters, and display it in the map. But now i want to display only street view in the map. 
I tried changing https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/....to https://www.google.co.in/maps/views/....But it did not work.
Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share what you tried and highlight what didnt work

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri getmap = Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll=29.9774614,31.1329645&cbp=0,30,0,0,-15");
Intent mapintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, getmap);
mapintent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapintent);
```